# How to use Realm notifications

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, realm

I am trying to write an application in OS X using a Realm database. In my program I need to wait for a Realm write to be complete then call up a new veiwcontroller. After much research it seems that using Realm's built in notification center would be appropriate. According to the Realm documentation the format should work like this

```
let token = realm.addNotificationBlock { notification, realm in
    viewController.updateUI()
}
```

I understand that this is a swift closure, but I am not sure how to use it. If I changed the code to this

```
let token = realm.addNotificationBlock { notification, realm in
   println("The realm is complete")
}
```

Would that print to my debugging screen when the write is complete? Or more simply how do I execute some code only after I receive the notification?

If I place the above code in my app I do not see my line in the debug screen all I see is the following:

> 2015-07-31 16:08:17.138 Therapy Invoice[27979:2208171]
>   RLMNotificationToken released without unregistering a notification.
>   You must hold on to the RLMNotificationToken returned from
>   addNotificationBlock and call removeNotification: when you no longer
>   wish to receive RLMRealm notifications.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make `notificationToken` an ivar:

```
var notificationToken: NotificationToken?


deinit{
    //In latest Realm versions you just need to use this one-liner
    notificationToken?.stop()

    /* Previously, it was needed to do this way
    let realm = Realm()
    if let notificationToken = notificationToken{
        realm.removeNotification(notificationToken)
    }
    */
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let realm = Realm()
    notificationToken = realm.addNotificationBlock { [unowned self] note, realm in
       self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
...
}
```

Comment: `realm.removeNotification`[deprecated](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/317), use `notificationToken.stop()`

Comment: notificationToken.stop() is old, use notificationToken.invalidate()

Answer (score 21):

From [Realm latest docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#notifications) (3.0.1):

Add `notificationToken.invalidate()` in order to unregister from the notification.

In Detail:

- Declare the `notificationToken` as class variable

  ```
  var notificationToken: NotificationToken?
  ```
- Set the `notificationToken` in `viewDidLoad()`

  ```
  notificationToken = realm.observe { [unowned self] note, realm in
     self.tableView.reloadData()
  }
  ```
- Unregister from the Notification in `viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool)`

  ```
  notificationToken?.invalidate()
  ```

*Edit notes:*

1. `notificationToken.stop()` is deprecated.
2. `realm.addNotificationBlock...` will cause the following error:

   > Value of type 'Realm' has no member 'addNotificationBlock'